# Angular 5 - Component is not available in the lazy loaded module

Tags: angular, angular5

I have implemented the lazy loaded module. I have

1. Parent Module
2. Shared Module
3. Child Module

I have one **test component** in the **shared module**. I have this component in **declarations part and exports part**.

I have imported this **shared module** in the **parent module**.
Since I have exported the **test component**, I can use this in **parent module**.

In **parent module**, I have exported the **Shared module**. When I access the **test component** in ** Child lazy loaded module**, I got the issue like test component is not a known element. 
Why I am getting this issue?

Comment: You should share the relevant code in your question.

Comment: Import the shared module in child modules as well.

Comment: I will share richard. Since this is the common need, I assumed code is not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the test component to be available in the child module, you have to import it in the child module. Not in the parent module.

Check out the official docs on shared modules: 
[Sharing Modules](https://angular.io/guide/sharing-ngmodules)

> Creating shared modules allows you to organize and streamline your
>   code. You can put commonly used directives, pipes, and components into
>   one module and then import just that module wherever you need it in
>   other parts of your app.